# MathJax equations goes on next line when used between sentence

Tags: javascript, html, css, equation, mathjax

I am using MathJax.js locally the equations are getting generated but the problem is the equation goes on the next line as shown in the image 
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this.
The main point is when i use the link of the server of MathJax.js it shows properly in the same line

```
<script src='../MathJax-master/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'>
</script> 
<script> 
MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: { displayMath: [   ['\\(','\\)'] ] } });
 /*MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: { displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ] } });*/
 MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
    "HTML-CSS": { scale: 100, linebreaks: { automatic: false } }, 
    SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic:false } },
    displayIndent: "2em", 
    displayAlign: "left" });
```

this is the code of the js nothing else is done and the laTEX is 
(\alpha_c/\alpha_t)

Comment: please provide more details. We need your code to tell you what wrong you are doing. It will help if you can copy paste your code in codepen or jsfiddle. Please help us help you.

Comment: @viCky Code updated

Comment: have you tried using:  width: "container". http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/CommonHTML.html?highlight=linebreak . Also it will help if you can provide codepen so we can debug the error.

Comment: You specifically set the delimiters for displayMath to `\(...\)` (which is the default for inlineMath delimiters). So this is the expected result. You need to either set inlineMath delimiters and use those or stop overwriting the default inline delimiters.